# Where to place static variables (for type definition) in Python

Tags: python

I am not sure if the title was clear (I am a bit new here), so let me elaborate... Imagine I have the following simple project structure:

```
test/
|-- __init__.py
|-- windows.py
|-- elements.py
|-- test.py
```

`windows.py` is as follows:

```
from elements import Container

class WindowTypes:
    TYPE_1 = 1
    TYPE_2 = 2

class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.container1 = Container(WindowTypes.TYPE_1)
```

On the other hand, `elements.py`:

```
from windows import WindowTypes

class Container:
    def __init__(self, win_type):
        if win_type is WindowTypes.TYPE_1:
            print('Loading stuff specific for windows of type 1')
        else:
            print('Doing something else')
```

If in `test.py` I make an instance of the Window class:

```
from windows import Window

Window()
```

I am aware that I will run into a circular import error. However I need a descriptive variable to describe the types of objects I can create from the `Window` class. How is this situation treated in Python?

PD: For this case I can create another file to hold the types, but my project is much larger than the represented, is it still good?

Comment: I would recommend putting the enum class (`WindowTypes`) in a separate module. You might also want to looking into using actual enums (built-in in Python 3 and installable as `enum34` in Python 2). In addition, relative imports should use `from .x import y` (note the leading dot).

Comment: This isn't really to do with static variables, rather circular imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways I can think to deal with this:

1. Instead of importing specific names from a module with `from ... import ...`, just import the module itself. For example, in `windows.py`, instead of writing

   ```
   from elements import Container
   ```

   just write

   ```
   import elements
   ```

   and then when you want to create a `Container`, do it like this:

   ```
   self.container1 = elements.Container(WindowTypes.TYPE_1)
   ```

   The advantage of this approach is that you don't actually force the `elements` module to have anything in it named `Container` at the time the module is imported, and that way you solve your circular import problem.

   I won't get too far into the details of why this works (unless you're interested, I can edit), but the gist is that the first step in the import process involves marking the module as already being imported, so that any further `import` statements referring to the same module won't result in loading the file all over again. So if you import `A` which imports `B` which imports `A` again, the second time that `import A` is encountered, it doesn't do anything and doesn't continue the loop. You can take advantage of this to allow what would otherwise be circular imports in many cases, though there are times it doesn't work.
2. Or you can just move the window types to a separate module. The type enumeration is something that can exist independently of the `Window` class, and it's not a bad idea to have it completely separate so that code which wants to use the types doesn't have to bring in the full `windows` module. I see why you'd want to keep the types together with the `Window` implementation, since the type isn't really used for anything else, but I don't think that's so necessary that it should keep you from moving the enumeration to a separate module. The implementation of windows could definitely span several modules. You could even make it a subpackage if you like, i.e. have a structure like

   ```
   test/
   |-- __init__.py
   |-- windows/
       |-- __init__.py
       |-- types.py
       |-- window.py
   |-- elements.py
   |-- test.py
   ```

   (adjust as needed for your purposes).

Comment: Third, and in my opinion best, option: place `from elements import Container` at the end of `windows.py`

Comment: @MadPhysicist True, that is an option, but I disagree that it's the best because it negatively impacts readability of the code.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think so.

Comment: @MadPhysicist That's because putting the import statement at the end doesn't introduce the identifier `Container` before using it.

Comment: The first way feels like a hack, i will use the second.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Doesn't the thrid way break every possible standard ever created

Comment: @ASMateus not that I'm aware of. It might be against PEP8, but it's a fairly common way of avoiding circular import problems.

Comment: @ASMateus (3 comments up) The first way is definitely not a hack. It's an exceedingly common practice, and is the solution I would use. That being said, if you don't like it, you're free not to use it, but just keep in mind that you're doing so because of your own personal preferences and not because of any widely accepted best practice.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I said it feels like a hack, because you can see some sort of circular calling from a module to the other. I still do not know what is better, class import or module level import. But that is what I wanted to mean

Comment: word of warning, don't name the file `types.py`, you can/will get confusing errors when trying to import stuff depending on your version of python

Comment: @Mattwmaster58 Which version did you get errors with? I did a quick test with every version from 3.5 to 3.11 and they all worked fine for me. (Plus, in the specific case from this answer it'd be `import windows.types`, not just `import types`, if that's what you were worried about)